# Database Design for Plants and Nutrients Inventory

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am starting to design a relational MySQL database to keep a plants and nutrients inventory but I keep running in circles on how to design the tables.

I have various types of plants and various types of nutrients.

I am having trouble deciding how the tables are going to relate with each other, if I make some simple related tables and then make sub-tables to store specific information.

Comment: Step 1: Read up on [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) and normal forms. Step 2: Apply those design principles to your data. It sounds like you have a classic *many-to-many* association, which usually involves three tables.

Comment: I would expect to see a table of plants (plant_id, species, etc.), and a table of nutrients (although this may be redundant if you're only looking at elements and not compounds), and a table which records the quantity of each nutrient in each plant (plant_id,nutrient_id - or just element, and parts_per_million)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the relation between them, Just create two separate table for plant and nutrient with ID and later you can create a sub-table which can relate one plant with many nutrients and vice versa using their ID or how ever you want.